# I'm considering placing a while loop inside a parent while loop that has the exact same conditions. Can I avoid this with a better object iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, while-loop, each

I'm considering placing a while loop with the conditions `(qgLLInco = 1)` inside a while loop with the exact same conditions.

The idea is to exit the loop immediately, instead of appending each item that meets the `if` conditions, because there will be more than one.

In the example code below, which is where I'm at right now, the `.each` method, I beleive, will cause the code to iterate the entire array. Is there a different method I should be using, to exit the loop as soon as it appends one item out of the array? Or should I add a second while loop, with the same conditions, inside of the `if` statement?

```
while (qgLLInco = 1) {
    $(qgAnsArray[]).find('jOption').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('correct') == 'false') {
            $('#qg_options').append('<li><span class="qg_option">' + $(qgAnsArray[t]).text() + '</span></li>');
            qgLLInco = 2;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `return false;` inside `$.each()` to break the loop.

```
$(qgAnsArray[]).find('jOption').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('correct') == 'false')
    {
        $('#qg_options').append('<li><span class="qg_option">' + $(this).text() + '</span></li>');
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you only want the first instance of an element, you can use `first()`:

```
var elem = $(qgAnsArray[]).find('jOption[correct="false"]').first();
```

Comment: I was under the impression this only returned false for the anonymous function executed by `$.each()` (unless you mean to return false after a condition is met).

Comment: @Seiyria If I understand him correctly, he should be able to do away with the while loop.

Comment: Right, but if you `return false;` in the anonymous function, it doesn't actually stop further function executions of `$.each()` (or it's parent functions), so it doesn't change anything to have it there.

Comment: Returning false does prevent further iterations of `$.each()`: "We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @JasonP Works perfect